# How to fill textboxes on 2nd page

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to enter the value of cell `C4`, which is gotten from an input box which assigns the value to the cell, into the search box after submitting at the first page but I am not able to as I keep getting an error 438. Is there something wrong with my codes after the input box?

And is there a way that I can have the codes wait until cell `C4` is assigned with the value in the input box then continue with filling in the 2nd page?

Also, I am using Internet Explorer 11, what should my `objItem.FullName Like` be if I want to use the opened browser to work on?

```
Option Explicit
Const word1 As String = "C2"
Const word2 As String = "C3"
Const word3 As String = "C4"

Public Sub Test()
    Dim objWindow As Object
    Dim objIEApp As Object
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim wordthree As String
    On Error GoTo Fin
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
    For Each objItem In objWindow
        If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*iexplore*") Then
            Set objIEApp = objItem
        End If
    Next objItem
    If objIEApp Is Nothing Then
        Set objIEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        objIEApp.Visible = True
    End If
    With objIEApp
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "google.com"
        While Not .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        .Document.all.q.Value = Range(word1).Value
        '.Document.all.q.Value = Range(word2).Value
        .Document.forms(0).submit

    End With
    3word = InputBox("Enter 3rd word: ")
    Range("C4").Value = wordthree
    With objIEApp
        .Visible = True
        While Not .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        .Document.all.q.Value = Range(word3).Value
        .Document.forms(0).submit
    End With
Fin:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & _
        Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Set objWindow = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: i have solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can spot here is that you're attempting to name your variables starting with a number. In the VB world (VBA, VB.Net etc. all included), this is not valid & your code won't work.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264773.aspx for more info on variable naming rules.

**Update:**

The next thing & reason you're getting the error, is that you need to include a call to exit the method before the error handling routine code is called. Your code above now worked correctly for me with this *"exit sub"* statement added.

```
    .Document.all.q.Value = Range(word3).Value
    .Document.forms(0).submit
End With

**Exit Sub**

Fin:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & _
```

Comment: Yes that is a problem, but it is not the cause of the OP's issue. If you change the name of `3work` to something valid the `438` error still occurs.

Comment: yes true that is my fault. i changed the variable name here for privacy purposes didnt realise that i put the number in front